# Maintain state of Search page after navigating back from details page in Angular Material table using Akita/State management

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-akita

I am looking for any working example where I can save the search filter state,pagination state after a click on the detail page and coming back to using the location.back() function.

I am using the Akita store and angular material table in my application to maintain the state.

I was going through one of the AkitaFilter plugins but they are lacking documentation and examples. Can anyone have a solution using any NGRX or Akita State management to save the state in the angular material table?

Comment: How we can use router to go back to previous url?

Comment: Can you please provide any example? Where we can navigate to previous url using router?

Comment: there is an answer but it includes a more raw form of javascript.. something like having the link do a request sending the state data and the rerouting to wherever

Answer (score 0):

you can store your current state of table in your localstorage  like this in each filter's function you can do

```
localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(this.store.getState()));
```

Alternatively you can store your `grid/table's` `filter` state in your `localstorage`, Like you can store `currentPage, sortOrdet` etc in your localstorage. Because if you want your data to be persistent even after navigation or page refresh so you can store in `localstorage` because `state` management `stores` are also services based architecture in which data can't be persistent.

You can do this in a way that inside your `pagination` button function you can store your current page in your `localstorage` each time your function will be called. And same goes for `sorting` function.

Comment: Thanks.. can you please provide any examples?

Comment: In my answer i gave you an example. In my answer i showed how you can store your current state in localStorage.

Comment: I was looking for answer to store and retrieve angular material pagination and sorting.